# Swagger Upload File with File format?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

Is there a way to define a File Format for the "Upload File" definition on an openAPI YAML file? (I'm displaying this using Swagger UI).

By File format, I mean the format of the content of the file.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by file format? Do you mean the file type ("Excel file", "Text file", etc.)? Or do you mean the internal structure of the file, e.g. "CSV file with two columns: ID (integer, > 0), Name (string, non-empty)"? Or something else?

Comment: The later, I'm looking for a way to document how the content of the file should be found

Comment: The best thing you probably can do is to describe the format using the `description` field.

Comment: I'll keep looking into it, but for now, I think you are right, I can use the description to have at least something published. Thanks